# Unable to install nsgclient on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am trying to install nsgclient(NetScaler Gateway Client for Linux) from Software centre on Ubuntu 20.04. I get an error

```
Unable to install nsgclient. The following packages have unmet dependencies.
```

This installation works fine with previous versions of Ubuntu(like 16 and 18). How can I install it??

Comment: There is no `msgclient` in Ubuntu repositories (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=msgclient) and we cannot read and help with messages we cannot see. You mention Ubuntu 16 & 18; since there is no 16 or 18 release (*yy* being used by *snap* based releases) but there is Ubuntu Core 16 & Ubuntu Core 18, are you talking about a *snap* which don't have dependencies as they are built in. *I also looked for `nsgclient` too assuming typo as you use both*

Comment: sorry my bad. I was installing this via software center, so had to manually type it and it came out wrong. It is indeed nsgclient

Comment: As I mentioned in prior comment, `nsgclient` is Ubuntu software either (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=nsgclient&searchon=names) so providing a source for it, or clear messages may help. I'm aware of some Cisco packaged software no longer working because it's *out-of-date* with Qt4 dependencies (Qt4 is EOL & no longer available for *focal*) but those issues will be seen in messages are cannot see, only you can. You also didn't clear up the *snap* or incorrect Ubuntu release detail you mentioned.

Comment: You have to search on Citrix site - something like https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-gateway/ .

Answer (score 4):

You can get `nsgclient18_64` from https://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-gateway/earlier-versions/netscaler-gateway-plug-in-VPN_EPA_Clients_Ubuntu_18.html

You can do it via terminal:

```
curl http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/libnm-util2_1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb -sO
sudo dpkg -i libnm-util2_1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb 
curl http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager/libnm-glib4_1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb -sO
sudo dpkg -i libnm-glib4_1.10.6-2ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
sudo apt install -y libnl-cli-3-200 libappindicator1 libproxy1-plugin-webkit libdbusmenu-gtk4 libnl-nf-3-200
sudo dpkg -i nsgclient18_64.deb
```

Comment: The client tends to segfault on ubuntu 20. If anyone is looking how to work around it (as citrix so far didn't fix the issue), set the environment variable DCONF_PROFILE to some nonsense before starting the NSGClient (and THEN go to the VPN web page).

Comment: In 2021 I think it's updated now. We also need `resolvconf` package.